# Is there a way to count peaks in data based on field calculator functions?

Tags: qgis

I would like to count the number of peaks in a dataset which is saved as a csv file. The data is rainfall values from the last 12 years, saved in 5 min increments and the number of rows involved is well beyond the capabilities of excel.

using excel the following formula does what I am after

=IF(AND(B3>B2,B3>B4), "Peak","")

Is there anyway to replicate this using QGIS field calculator?

Below is an example of the data, I have removed dates and used ID numbers

[image]

Comment: Could you provide two to three rows of data to make answering the question more easier and on point?

Comment: So you want to identify rows whose rainfall value is higher than previous row, and less than following row. Rows are sorted by ID

Comment: Joseph - how would I apply this to the field calculator? would that not mean I would have to type every ID number into the equation?

Comment: JGH - yes, thats exactly what I'm after, only using a formula in QGIS field calculator, and not in excel as shown above as the dataset is too large for Excel to handle it. Even if broken into excel sized chunks i would have to run the analysis multiple time to complete all the rows which is not ideal

Comment: On a side note, you have about 1,250,000 rows. A dataset of this size would be much easier to manage in a database rather than in a csv file.

Comment: I have it saved as a txt file at present but when wanting to edit it in QGIS i have to save it as a non-geometry csv. I would be open to SQL suggestions also if there is one going.. just been wrecking my head trying to do this in one swoop rather than as many smaller excel files

Comment: With a SQL query, you could try to join the table to itself twice, first on ID = ID - 1 and then on ID = ID + 1, then select and update the rows based on your conditions.

Comment: Postgres has the `lag` and `lead` row accessors in an ordered `window`.

Comment: It is possible to use SQL queries on non DB layers in the DB Manager of QGIS. However I'm not sure if there are limitations to functionality. I would look into the lag and lead window functions that @JGH mentioned.